# Extension development using c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I want to do more practice for c/c++ language, someone recommended me to develop extension for other software, which is supposed to be newbie friendly

My first idea was extension(addon) for browsers, then I found that Opera/Firefox/Chrome all use javascript but not c/c++ for extension development.

Anyone recommend softwares which use c/c++ for their extension development?

I also found several similar question about how to earn programming skill, and most are answered to participate in opensource project. However I found these projects too huge, as a beginner I don't have any clue where to start with.

Comment: Nobody uses C/C++ for extension development.  They always pick either C or C++.  So should you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While perhaps not the browser plugin you're lookng for, you could take a look at the [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE as an example. It's a C++ written app using wxWidgets for it's GUI and has a C++ pluggable interface. There's not a great deal of plugins for it, so anything simple that can boost developer productivity would be useful to plenty of people. There's a [number](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_simple_%22Hello_World%22_plugin) of [wiki articles](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_Plug-in_which_modifies_CB%27s_Menus) to help you get started on it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop PHP/[Python](http://docs.python.org/extending/windows.html) module, [Opera/Firefox/Chrome plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652034/a-simple-hello-world-npapi-plugin-for-google-chrome), Miranda plugin, some Windows service.

If you need more practice you can try to develop a copy of some simple(or not simple) program.

Comment: I would like to develop Opear/Firefox/Chrome plugin but are they developed in c/c++?

Comment: Plugins for Firefox and Chrome can be written in C++ with NPAPI. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652034/a-simple-hello-world-npapi-plugin-for-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to write extension for some software in C++ then you may find following 2 is good.

1. Notepad++. (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

   You can take tamplete of Plugin from (http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/PluginTemplate/)
2. Wireshark. This is big project to do.

   But if you have any idea for any protocol then you can write plugin for that in wireshark.
   For more help you can follow (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/custom_dissector.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone recommend softwares which use c/c++ for their extension development?

There is a whole world of software that uses c/c++ for their extensions, it all depends on what field **you** are interested in. For example if you are interested in music and DSP, you can create VST instruments, which extend music applications with VST instruments. VST instruments and effects compile to dll files. If you are interested in graphics, you can write plugins for Photoshop, or Adobe Premiere.

> I also found several similar question about how to earn programming skill, and most are answered to participate in opensource project. However I found these projects too huge, as a beginner I don't have any clue where to start with.

If it helps, there are plenty of open source projects that are small, in fact one might say that there are far too many. Games are often a good starting point, in fact just working on a tetris clone will teach you a great deal. When I used to teach people programming, I would always suggest they begin by creating a tetris clone. Board games are great too, and you can do them all in the `console` so you won't have to worry about graphics libraries and all that *jazz*. Excellent starting points are Monopoly and Clue. Card games are good as well.

I know your question was about plugins, but I given you mentioned that aspect it seemed necessary to point out.