# How to call npapi plugin method in extension

Tags: c#, c++, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I have a test .dll file using C# with the following details

```
 Name : TestLibrary.dll
 Namespace name : TestLibrary
 Class Name : AddClass
 Method name : add(accepts two parameters)
 Language used : C#
```

I gave lugin path in manifest.json as below

```
 plugins : [{"path":"TestLibrary.dll", "public": true}]
```

And called like below

```
 var result = TestLibrary.AddClass.add(12,34)
```

But it returns me nothing. Please help me to correct this code. `Please provide me simple NPAPI plugin example with hello world program with NPAPI plugin in any example. I am confused with parameters / details / references need to be provided inside NPAPI plugin`

Comment: Your edit is basically just a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652034/a-simple-hello-world-npapi-plugin-for-google-chrome). You should spend some time with the resources given there, and then ask new specific questions if you are still having trouble.

Comment: @smorgan Thanks for your comment. And that Question was answered when Google chrome was a child and the Chrome versions have been changed. I have asked the Question for latest code samples... :-)

Comment: NPAPI isn't a Chrome API, it's a very stable cross-browser API, and as such it changes *very* slowly; the Chrome version is irrelevant. There have been no significant changes to NPAPI since the question I pointed you to. Everything in the top-voted answer is still the best answer to your question; no amount of bounty will cause there to be better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use C# to create a NPAPI Plugin. You must have a C++ library that exports the following entry points:

```
LIBRARY   my_plugin.dll

EXPORTS
  NP_GetEntryPoints     @1
  NP_Initialize         @2
  NP_Shutdown           @3
```

These entry points are the core to the NPAPI architecture. For examples, refer to the following answer [A simple hello world NPAPI plugin for Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652034/a-simple-hello-world-npapi-plugin-for-google-chrome)

Comment: I have seen many of your answers in stackoverflow and I am glad to have your response here.. I have seen them but they are referring to MDN. Where information is like finding salt in sea water. I hope you can help me with little more explanation. Please help me on this. I am struggling for this to understand. I dont want to use firebreath because I am only targeting Chrome.

Comment: Sol, The first thing I saw in your question is that your using C# which is incorrect, you need to use C++ for NPAPI and the link I specified above is a simple Hello World plugin that should work. Try understanding that (there is a blog link there that is extremely good), and run the hello world. What @smorgan said regarding calling methods is what you should normally do.

Answer (score 2):

NPAPI plugins don't add utility classes to your JS namespace, they allow you to instantiate `<object>`/`<embed>` elements. You need to instantiate your plugin in HTML, and then call methods on that plugin element.