# Simple example for NPAPI plugin

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, npapi, gecko

I'm trying to find a simple example on how to write an NPAPI plugin that will be bundled with my Chrome extension.

The thing I need to do with the NPAPI is simply to run an already existing local program that I have the local path for.

Could not find any simple examples that will allow me to do this.

Comment: Running an existing local program isn't specific to plugins. I'd look into [example plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652034/a-simple-hello-world-npapi-plugin-for-google-chrome) and how to start local programs separately, then put the two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firebreath NPAPI framework seems to have decent documentation: http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home

Answer (score 3):

I start from
OSX 
https://github.com/niw/open_with_default

Linux/ WinNT
http://code.google.com/p/npapi-file-io/

thanks above

and then
Put them together into my npapi plugin

have a look at 
https://github.com/tg123/chrome-hostadmin