# Chrome extension for wget downloading

Tags: google-chrome-extension, download, wget

Can I develop a Chrome extension that will, upon a click of a button, download the current webpage using the `wget` command? I'd like to know whether that is conceptually possible. The reason I want `wget` as opposed to simply saving the page is that with `wget`, it is possible to specify many different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I know, the only one possibility to do such stuff, it's through  **[NPAPI plugin](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html)**

And if it's only for Your private usage (as not on all OSes You could have wget command), You could launch wget through AJAX :

*Chrome Extension => AJAX call => Web server script => Wget launched*

Comment: Fedir, thanks for your answer. So by using NPAPI, will the extension work for any computer running on Linux? (since Linux has the `wget` command.)

Comment: Yes, You could achieve it. There are lots of questions around Chrome & NPAPI on StackOverflow. Ex. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382794/simple-example-for-npapi-plugin