# Missing npruntime/npapi samples from new mozilla-central repository

Tags: mozilla, npapi, npruntime

I am looking for npruntime/npapi plugin samples which were earlier present under "https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/2255d7d187b2/modules", But it looks like these samples were removed from the mozilla-central repository possibly for all good reasons,

Where can I find these samples and process to compile those under Ubuntu/Linux environment.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652034/a-simple-hello-world-npapi-plugin-for-google-chrome).

Answer (score 3):

You can get NPAPI headers and samples from https://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/

Building sample process:

1. check out the repository.

   $ svn checkout http://npapi-sdk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ npapi-sdk-read-only
2. build basic sample.

   $ cd npapi-sdk-read-only/samples/unix-basic

   $ make